# order two list join and return ordered by date c# with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need an help here! I always get an error from linq (wrong expression). Should work but it´s not... I don´t get any error when order by max Id but I need to get the Id of the max date group by IDFiscal and CodigoXPCliente. I tried diferent ways but I always get an error.

```
var queryTemp =
            (from u in _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.TipoUsuario == "Cliente")
             join ass in context.AssessoresCliente on u.Id equals ass.ApplicationUser.Id into temp_ass
             from temp in temp_ass
             select new ListaBaseCliente_Atendimento
             {
                 Nome = u.Nome,
                 IDFiscal = u.IDFiscal,
                 Email = u.Email,
                 PhoneNumber = u.PhoneNumber,
                 DataPessoa = u.DataPessoa,
                 DataCadastro = temp.DataCadastro,
                 CodigoXPCliente = temp.CodigoXPCliente,
                 AssessorCambio = temp.AssessorCambio,
                 AssessorProtect = temp.AssessorProtect,
                 CodigoAssessorXP = temp.CodigoAssessorXP,
                 ClienteCambio = temp.ClienteCambio,
                 ClienteProtect = temp.ClienteProtect,
                 ClienteXP = temp.ClienteXP,
                 AssessorXP = temp.AssessorXP,
                 CadastroValido = true,
                 DataRegistroUsuario = temp.DataRegistroUsuario,
                 DataArquivo = DataHoje,
                 ContaXPNova = temp.ContaXPNova,
                 ImportacaoBitrix = temp.ImportacaoBitrix,
                 IdAssessoresCliente = temp.Id,
                 RegistroValido = temp.RegistroValido
             }).AsEnumerable(); 

    
    var agrup = from s in queryTemp group s by new { s.IDFiscal, s.CodigoXPCliente } into g
           select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.DataRegistroUsuario).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: *I always get an error* -- Which error?

Comment: Do the orderby first like this : var agrup = queryTemp.OrderByDescending(t => t.DataRegistroUsuario).GroupBy(s => new { s.IDFiscal, s.CodigoXPCliente }).ToList();

Comment: Arnold! I Get this error: Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side.

Comment: jdweng! Your answer didn´t work. I Get an error from linq.

Comment: EF Core 6 should handle this query. Which version do you use?

Comment: EF Core 5! I will upgrade everything to 6.0 and return as soon I will finish and test it. Does any one as an working example? Working fine on SQL (inserted on code)...

Comment: Svyatoslav Danyliv  Fixed my problem! I was afraid to stop for upgrate because I didn´t had the time for it. But now it´s working like I charm. How can I mark the solution answered by Svyatoslav Danyliv? @SvyatoslavDanyliv you are realy good! Congrats and thank you very much.